# Лямбда-выражения (ошибка - Target type of a lambda conversion must be an interface)

Tags: java, интерфейс, лямбда-выражение

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Car {
    void star();
}
```

```
public class Lada implements Car {

    @Override
    public void star() {
        System.out.println("Yes!!");
    }
}
```

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lada lada1 = new Lada();
        lada1.star();

        Lada lada2 = new Lada() {
            @Override
            public void star() {
                System.out.println("yes!");
            }
        };
        lada2.star();

        Lada lada3 = () -> System.out.println("No");/// ошибка 
        lada.star();

        Car car3 = () -> System.out.println("No");
        car3.star();
    }
}
```

**Вопрос**: почему эта запись неправильная, но при этом когда использую анонимный класс, там можно использовать класс `Lada`?

```
Lada lada3 = () -> System.out.println("No");///  ошибка
lada3.star();
```

Comment: Лямбда должна реализовывать функциональный интерфейс. А Lada - это не функциональный интерфейс, это класс, реализующий функциональный интерфейс.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо за ответ, но разве можно создать объект интерфейса?

Comment: Нельзя, можно только его реализовать, например через лямбду или класс.

Comment: @insolor, то есть теперь интерфейс будет хранить ссылку на объект ? Те данные которые, я объявил они будут принадлежать интерфейсу ?

Comment: Переменная будет хранить ссылку на объект, реализующий интерфейс (соответствующий интерфейсу). Интерфейс ничего не будет хранить. Данные будут "принадлежать" переменной.

Comment: @insolor, в данном случае, car3 - это переменная  и она хранить значение ? Правильно ли я Вас понял ?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Потому что целевым типом лямбда-выражения по определению является только функциональный интерфейс, т.е. интерфейс, имеющий ровно один метод.

Любой же класс по определению имеет как минимум одного предка `Object`, у которого есть свои методы (как минимум `hashCode`, `equals`, `toString`, `clone`), а значит, нарушается требование к количеству методов.

В самом деле, при присваивании лямбды к ссылке-классу `Lada`, нельзя определить, к какому из методов этого класса относится лямбда-выражение.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, то есть, я могу использовать классы и интерфейсы у которых только один метод ?

Comment: Присвоить значение лямбды можно только только ссылке на экземпляр функционального интерфейса, как в вашем коде: `Car car = () -> System.out.println("111");`

Comment: Статья Б.Гётца [State of  the Lambda:: Target Typing](https://cr.openjdk.org/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-final.html): _A lambda expression can only appear in a context whose target type is a functional interface._